# respective posistion of d and p orbitals in a multielectronic species

Tags: atoms, atomic-structure

we write the electronic configuration of atoms as [noble gas core]4s2 3d10.that is that due to energy considerations(aufbau principle) in multielectronic species.
what i want to know is whether the 4s subshell occupies a posistion before the 3d orbital in reality,or is this just written in textbooks to easily follow the aufbau principle.

Comment: Orbitals aren't situated at a certain distance, they are regions of probability distribution. Only distances to be considered are average, mean square average, modal probability distance etc. But comparing these distances actually does nothing good.

Comment: *"whether 4s subshell occupies a position before 3d"* - occupies a position **where?** In an atom, there are only probability distributions of electrons - there are no queues where orbitals can be assigned positions. In terms of shell number (a wrong concept when using orbitals), 4s is 4th shell, and 3d is 3rd - but as you said, due to energy differences, 4s is generally filled first.